# Android Strobe on S6 and possibly other hardware not doing what is expected

Tags: android, flashlight

I am creating an app that works with the Flashlight using the Camera libraries and not Camera2. I have got the normal flashlight right and decided to do a strobe function as well. The Strobe method is a simple turnon and turnoff with a sleep in between each one. The frequency can be changed by a seekbar value I pass through every time. Now this works fantastic on the following hardware I tested :

1. HTC Desire 626
2. Samsung Galaxy Note 3
3. Huawei P8
4. HTC One

But on the Samsung S6 it seems like it is battling. The faster I let the Strobing go to slower it is getting and the periods between on and off is random.

I execute the following code until it is stopped by the user :

```
                    camera.setParameters(paramsOn);
                    SystemClock.sleep(delay);
                    camera.setParameters(paramsOff);
                    SystemClock.sleep(delay);
```

Above I use SystemClock's sleep for the delay. I have also tried Thread.Sleep, which once again had the same awesome experience on the other devices except for the S6. My assumption is that if this is happening on the S6 it might happen on other hardware as well.

I have also tried different implementations and threading approaches. I also downloaded other strobing apps on the S6 to make sure I am not doing anything strange and these apps are also not working on the S6 devices. I have  tried on 2 Samsung S6 devices just to make sure.

Any ideas will be welcome. I am a bit stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Camera API is just  a thin layer on top of actual hardware drivers which are **very** dependent on particular vendor (or even model of the device). Therefore unless something is explicitly written in official documentation you should not make any assumptions.

In particular, there is no guarantee that applied `Camera` parameters will be applied instantly or, in fact, will be applied at all. We had a lot of cases where parameters might be just silently rejected by camera (without producing any sort of errors).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dmitry. How do you overcome it when you encounter it then ?

Comment: I just don't. I think because the problem is so dependent on vendor it is pointless to try to come up with workarounds which won't work reliably anyway.

Comment: I have changed the app to give the user t he option to switch between Camera and Camera2 if the other is too slow. It does not fix the problem though but does the job.